# RSYSLOG from Linux server to Windows machine

Tags: linux, windows, rsyslog

I have my application server running in a Linux server which generates application specific logs. I want these logs to be captured in a different machine. Previously I used RSYSLOG to capture these logs in another Linux server. Now I want these logs to be captured in a Windows Server. I have seen RSYSLOG provides a Windows agent which I can, but it seems to be a licensed feature(http://www.rsyslog.com/windows-agent/windows-agent-download/). Is there any other open source which I can use for this purpose?. Thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at nxlog, that should do the trick. Or if its just bare bones log forwarding, what about the Splunk Universal Forwarder?

[nxlog - windows logging tool](https://nxlog.co/)

[Splunk Universal Forwarder](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/download/universal-forwarder.html)